# How to make an NSSplitView transparent without having the splitter disappear?

Tags: cocoa, transparent, nssplitview, nscolor

I've extended my window so that it has a button content border. The problem is that my NSSplitView covers the border. My thoughts were that I could make the split view transparent (but the controls on top of it opaque).

The following image shows what I am looking for, but with the missing splitter:

[image: Screenshot with missing splitter]

See how the bottom of the window has the button on it. This is the effect I am trying to achieve, but without any luck. The code that I am attempting to use is:

```
CALayer *transparentViewLayer = [CALayer layer];
[viewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreateGenericRGB(
                                                      256.0,
                                                      256.0,
                                                      256.0,
                                                      0)]; //RGB plus Alpha Channel
[splitView setWantsLayer:YES]; // view's backing store is using a Core Animation Layer
[splitView setLayer: transparentViewLayer];
```

If I do NOT set the transparentViewLayer, then I end up with the following:

[image: Splitter but hidden bottom bar]

Which shows the spitter, but hides the windows bottom bar. I have also tried subclassing `NSSplitView` and adding the following:

```
- (void) drawRect: (NSRect) dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed: 0.0 green: 255.0 blue: 0.0 alpha: 155.0] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
} // End of drawRect
```

Which left me with a green splitter and no alpha for the windows bottom bar. Any ideas on how I can achieve the effect I am looking for? (I want the bottom bar with my buttons and the splitter visible).

Answer (score 0):

In your subclass, don't override `-[NSSplitView drawRect:]`. Instead, override `-drawDividerInRect:` and draw your divider ONLY in that rect. **Always** [consult the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) *first* when you want to "bend" a class to your will.